# Azure WebApp + MySQL and Entity Framework : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have just deployed my web application on azure using Web App + MySQL app service. 
I use entity framework for the database and after the deployment I am getting the "The system cannot find the file specified" exception. I think it has to do something about connection strings. I think that the application cannot actually connect the database.
I spent many days trying to figure out how to fix it. I've gone through so many tutorials about this but no success.

[Application Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAiFq.png)

[MySQL in App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n36Tz.png)

I can only post 2 pictures.

This is the DbContext I used 
to create a LocalDB, I am not sure how to change it to make a connection with the Database on Azure.

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
public AppDbContext() : base("Valtrends")
    {
        InitializeDbContext();   
    }

    public DbSet<FactorType> FactorTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ComplexType> ComplexTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DataLoader.Entities.Version> Versions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DefaultPlotData> DefaultPlotData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GraphBucket> GraphBuckets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<XfactorFrom> XfactorsFrom { get; set; }
    public DbSet<XfactorTo> XfactorsTo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DistributionData> DistributionData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bin> Bins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DefaultPlotSettings> DefaultPlotSettings { get; set; }

    private void InitializeDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new AppDbInitializer());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<FactorType>().HasMany(m => m.CompatibilityListXY).WithMany();
    }

}
```

Comment: please add some code snippet to help us understand your problem.

Comment: What connection string you've used? how you are connecting web app to database?

Comment: Well, this is where I am lost. I'm not sure how to use and wher to find the connection string. According to Azure the MySQL server is running on the same instance side by side with your web server hosting the site. These are the app settings. I added some images to the original post.

Comment: As I can understand, you've created a web app and MySQL in App DB.

Comment: I created an ASP.NET web application using entity framework which uses ISS Express on my pc to create a LocalDB, but when I try to deploy it on Azure, I don't know how to change the code. I found some tutorials, but they all used different metods to connect to the database I could make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use MySQL in-app, I suggest you could firstly find the connectionstring by using the ftp.

You could firstly set the deployment credentials and use this username and passowrd access the webapplicaiton's ftp. Like below image shows:

Set the  deployment credentials.
[image]

Locate the mysql folder and find the MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt as below:

Path:ftp://{url}.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/data/mysql/

[image]

You will find the connection string as below:

```
Database=localdb;Data Source=127.0.0.1:52739;User Id=azure;Password=6#vWHD_$
```

Note:The right connection string in your web config is like below, the connection string you get from the txt is wrong:

```
Database=azuredb;Data Source=127.0.0.1;User Id=azure;Password=6#vWHD_$;port=52739
```

Update: I suggest you could use GetEnvironmentVariable method to get the connection string, since the port of your my sql will be changed if restart the web service. You could try below codes to get the conneciton string and convert it to right format.

Get connection string and format it sample:

```
  public static string connStrToArray()
        {
            string connStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb").ToString();
            string[] connArray = Regex.Split(connStr, ";");
            string connectionstring = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < connArray.Length; i++)
            {

                if (i == 1)
                {
                    string[] datasource = Regex.Split(connArray[i], ":");
                    connectionstring += datasource[0] + string.Format(";port={0};", datasource[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    connectionstring += connArray[i] + ";";
                }
            }

            return connectionstring;
        }
```

Besides, I guess your localdb is used sql server, if you want to use mysql to become the EF data server provider, you need install the MySql.Data.Entity(you could find it in the Nuget Package) and use Database.SetInitializer to set the SqlGenerator to MySqlClient.

More details, you could refer to below dbcontext codes:

```
namespace TestForMySQL
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {

        public static string connStrToArray()
        {
            string connStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb").ToString();
            string[] connArray = Regex.Split(connStr, ";");
            string connectionstring = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < connArray.Length; i++)
            {

                if (i == 1)
                {
                    string[] datasource = Regex.Split(connArray[i], ":");
                    connectionstring += datasource[0] + string.Format(";port={0};", datasource[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    connectionstring += connArray[i] + ";";
                }
            }

            return connectionstring;
        }

        public MyContext( )
        {

            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connStrToArray();
        }

        static MyContext()
        {

            //This is important
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
        }


        public virtual DbSet<Mytest> MyEntities2 { get; set; }
    }

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TestForMySQL.MyContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            //Change the SqlGenerator to MySql very important
            SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());

        }

        protected override void Seed(TestForMySQL.MyContext context)
        {
            context.MyEntities2.AddOrUpdate(new Mytest()
            {
                Id = 1
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public class Mytest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

---

> what does the url in :ftp://{url}.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/data/mysql/ stand for? The URL of the app service doesn't work for me

You could find the ftp url and username in the overview like below:

See the FTP hostname and FTP/deployment username.

[image]

---

Update:

> I have changed the credentials, but I have only URL, App Service plan/pricing tier and Continuous delivery status in the right column of Essentials

You could download the publish profile which contains the ftp url.

See below image:

[image]

The file:

[image]

---

Besides, there are another way you could find the storage connection string.

You could use kudu tool to directly see the files in your web service.

More details, you could refer to below steps.

1.Find the Advanced Tools in DEVELOPMENT TOOLS click go.

[image]

2. Click dubug console's cmd.
   [image]

3.Locate the right folder(data\mysql) and find the MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt file.
Click the Edit button.
[image]

Comment: what does the url in :ftp://{url}.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/data/mysql/ stand for? The URL of the app service doesn't work for me

Comment: If you changed the deployment credentials, you could find the ftp login url and username in the overview. See my answer.

Comment: I have changed the credentials, but I have only URL, App Service plan/pricing tier and Continuous delivery status in the right column of Essentials

Comment: I guess you have enabled the Continuous delivery in your web service. You could also find the url in the publish profile. See my update answer.

Comment: So I added a nuget package MySql.Data.Entity to the Presentation Layer Project in my solution and added the connection string to web.config and used it in the constructor in my AppDbContext and send it to the constructor of the base DbContext.                                                              Now I am getting  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Comment: BTW. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have written a test demo on my computer, it works well. I suggest you could check your connection string to make sure the user name, password, prot number is right. This connection string could only be used after you have published the application.

Comment: I had a error in the connection string but after I fixed it I get a new exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known. This in the web.config file  `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MonkeyFist" connectionString="Database=localdb;Data Source=###.#.#.#:#####;User Id=azure;Password=XXXXXXXXX" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: And my DbContext constructor                                                           `public AppDbContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "MonkeyFist")
        {
            InitializeDbContext();
        }`

Comment: So I changed the connection string to this `connectionString="Database=azuredb;Data Source=127.0.0.1;User Id=azure;Password=6#vWHD_$; port=XXXXX"` and it seems that it work. I get No provider supporting the InsertAll operation for this datasource was found now.

Comment: I think it's InsertAll method of EFUtilities, I am going to try to fix it now

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net, try printing connection string using,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb").ToString());
}
```

This will print your whole connction string

Now, `$conn_str` will give you the connection string.

and from connection string you can extract `host`, `username` and `password` for your MySQL Database.

you can use a function to do this for you,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conn_str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb").ToString();
        connStrToArray(conn_str);
    }
    public void connStrToArray(string connStr)
    {
        string[] connArray = Regex.Split(connStr, ";");
        string[] connArray2 = new string[] {};
        string[] keyArray = new string[] {"Database", "Data Source", "User ID", "Password"};
        for (int i = 0; i < connArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Response.Write(keyArray[i] + ":" + connArray[i].Substring(connArray[i].IndexOf("=") + 1).ToString() + "<br />");
        }
    }
```

find more about Asp.net and MySQL connection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054430/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-using-asp-net).

Comment: I am using asp.net

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow, can you write me how to do it?

Comment: Hope this helps, and a combination of PHP and MySQL is perfect and suggested.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not really sure about this code. TrimStart removes all occurences of certain character, so can you then split the string by it? And split returns a array of strings and then you are indexing the connarray by a string, not an integer? Also I can't use PHP in my project. I will try to make it work and let you know how I advanced.

Comment: If you find my Answer Helpful, Accept the answer, so that others with the same problem can benefit from it.