# I want to learn how to create a windows application which will be connected to a server

Tags: windows, web, client

I want to learn how to create a windows application which will be connected to a server and will  fetch the data from server and can perform various functions. For example a library app on which we can view issued books, place hold on book etc.

I am a student and have basic knowledge about databases, web application and web architectures.

Comment: Please ask questions. Specific technical questions. This is not a "I do not read the manual at all, please explain it to me totally" website - this is way too broad for the format here. You already have what you need to ask questions in the manuals that are online for .net. There are TONS of tutorials building an application as you mention. You do not ask a single question.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a window application in .net with using Visual Studio, both .net have libraries to connect with MYSQL database.

here is how you can connect with your mysql database
[Connecting to a mySQL database using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054430/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-using-asp-net)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but please don't answer off-topic questions. They should be closed. This question is off-topic because it is too broad and/or asking for off-site resources.