# Visual Studio ASP.Net Using MySQL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

If I am using Visual Studio 2019, how do I correctly set a new ASP.Net project to use MySQL for auth rather than Microsoft SQL?

I've got MySQL for VS installed along with their connector, when I look in server explorer I can see MySQL as a data source type, however when I am on the connected services section to add the required DB to the project itself, MySQL doesn't seem to come up as a data source.

I appreciate there are ways to "back door" it and built myself, however if possible I'd like to use the basic starting point you get with MSSQL on ASP.NET but with a MySQL database.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting to a mySQL database using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054430/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-using-asp-net)

Comment: Visual Studio 2020? Is that a thing?

Comment: no, I'm talking in the context of as a Visual Studio Service Dependencie in the project rather than manually. With the MS SQL system you can just create a project with their DB and it does all of it for you.

Comment: I get https://i.gyazo.com/2eefdbc943e48cdfaf2263bffc708f45.png in my server browser but https://i.gyazo.com/8991f0c5c949370d13fd95457b092dce.png on dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

If you using ASP.NET (.NET Framework)!

Simple way to connect to MySQL:

1. Add a new module (*if you are interested:  using this method you can
   connect both MySQL and MSSQL databases at the same time.).

   ```
   Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
   ```

   Imports System.Data.SqlClient

   ```
   Module SQL
       Public Function GetConnectionMySQLServer() As MySqlConnection
           Dim conn As String = "server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
                                 user=xxx;
                                 database=xxx;
                                 port=xxxx;
                                 password=xxxx;"
           Return New MySqlConnection(conn)
       End Function

       Public Function GetConnectionSQLServer() As SqlConnection
           Dim conn As String = "server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
                                 User ID=xxx; 
                                 Password=xxx;
                                 Database=xxx"
           Return New SqlConnection(conn)
       End Function
   End Module
   ```
2. Exmaple of using:

   Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

   ```
   Public Class Page
       Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

   Protected Sub btnAplly(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAplly.Click
       Using con As MySqlConnection = GetConnectionMySQLServer()
           con.Open()
           Dim sql As String = "select count(*) as cnt from users"
           Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
           Dim read As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
           read.Read()
           label1.Text = "exist " & read.Item("cnt") & " users"
           con.Close()
       End Using
   End Sub
   End Class
   ```

if you using c# you can use: https://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying (if possible) to do it with the service dependencie level in VS not by adding extra code